# Mouse Lag on External Monitor

Tags: windows-7, laptop, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, dvi

Hooked up my new [USB Docking Station](http://www.frys.com/product/7778688?site=sr:SEARCH:MAIN_RSLT_PG) in order to add a third monitor to my laptop. I'm running one monitor directly from the HDMI port on my laptop and one from the DVI-to-VGA on the docking station.

The monitor hooked up via DVI-to-VGA is experiencing extreme **mouse lag**.

**[Laptop](http://www.microcenter.com/product/410167/R700VJ-RS71_173_Laptop_Computer_-_Mocha) Specs:**
Windows 7 Pro
i7 processor
8gb ram
NVIDIA GT 635M graphics card

Is this a limitation of my USB Docking Station, or could this problem be solved by adding more RAM or upgrading my Graphics Card?

Comment: look if you have DPC issues: http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=140263 If yes, share the ETL file.

Comment: @magicandre1981 all vitals are relatively low. All signs are leading to the docking station :-/

Comment: but the USB driver for the docking station can cause the issue.